# How to push to mongoose schema property of type []

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, mern, react-fullstack

I'm using mongoose in my backend and was wondering if it was correct to set a schema property of type array like this?:

```js
comments: {
        type: [],
        required: false,
    }
```

Then push to a doc with the same property like this?:

```js
thread.comments.push({
                    commenter: req.user.username,
                    content: comment,
                });
                thread.save();
```

Answer (score 1):

As comments are children of your thread schema I'd suggest using [SubDocuments](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html):

```js
const commentSchema = new Schema({ 
   commenter: 'string',
   content: 'string' 
});

const threadSchema = new Schema({
  comments: [commentSchema],
  //...
});
```

Adding a comment:

```js
thread.comments.push({
   commentor: req.user.username,
   content: comment //the text of the comment
});
thread.save();
```